# Noun of "analysis-friendly"

Tags: expressions, nouns, adjectives

I am drafting the following sentence:

> We would like to adopt XXX given its much better readability and "analysis-friendly".

Obviously, *analysis-friendly* shall be used as an adjective, not like *readability* (as a noun).

I am writing to ask a proper way to adjust this term *analysis-friendly* and produce a noun.

Answer (score 1):

"… **being** analysis-friendly" should work. If a noun is needed, "**its analysis friendliness**" it will be (*a la* "eco friendliness," "user friendliness").